# Sequentially fade in divs when in viewport

Tags: jquery

I'm working on making a group of `div`'s fade in sequentially when they come into view on screen. However, I'm still having some trouble getting it to work.

I have about 5 `div`'s with the class `hideme` that I want to fade in slowly once they come into view.

The HTML for these `div`'s is quite simple:

```
<div class="hideme">
    <h3 class="text-white">one</h3>
    <img src="../link-to-image.jpg">
    <p>Some text that goes here!</p>
</div>
```

So far, I have this as my jQuery, but I'm not sure where it's gone wrong, i think there might be a few syntax errors in there.

```
var divs = $('.hideme');

$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    $.each(divs, function(i, item) {

        if($(item).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop();) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(item).css('opacity', '1');
        }, 1000 * i);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? that would help :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript console can be very useful in finding syntax errors as it will usually tell you exactly where they are.

In particular, this line:

```
if($(item).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop();) {
```

There should not be a semicolon inside the `if`:

```
if($(item).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhzJG/

Another thing to realize here is that `window.scroll` is going to fire many times in the process of scrolling down through the page.  You are going to end up with a whole bunch of `setTimeout`s stacking, which isn't really an ideal approach.

Comment: Nice man! They're all showing up nicely now! I do have an issue that the opacity change is happening when the div hits the top of the page, rather than fading in when in full view. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll just need to modify your logic for checking when to display them.  maybe add half of the screen height in addition to `scrollTop` or something.  You might also consider using `fadeIn` for an actual fade affect rather than instant appearing.  You can then also ditch the `setTimeout` all together.